# Why is Wicket not showing correct image on the WebPage?

Tags: image, wicket, bufferedimage

I have a folder with images: IMG1.jpg, IMG2.jpg, IMG3.jpg, IMG4.jpg.
I do:

```
BufferedImage _img = null;
_img = ImageIO.read(new File(PATH_TO_IMAGE + "\\IMG"+Id+".jpg")); //where id is the number.
```

Then the rest...

```
BufferedDynamicImageResource bufferedDynamicImage = new BufferedDynamicImageResource();
bufferedDynamicImage.setImage(_img);
Image ci = new Image("myImg", bufferedDynamicImage);
add(ci);
```

And what I get in the end is that although Wicket knows the exact path to some image (which is shown in Log.file) most time it gets random image from my folder. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: When these images aren't dynamic, is therea reason why you don't put them into your resources and just set the src-attribute?

Comment: @Nicktar , I have a tab in the WebPage. Under this tab are several tabs (how much, depends of Config-file). Each undertab has it own image. Images is placed in this folder (PATH_TO_FILE).Their names are "IMG"+index_of_undertab. And when I want to load some undertab (placing the right image), this problem occur.

Comment: Ooh, it is somehow depends of browser cache!

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, what about

```
Image ci = new Image("myImg");
ci.add(AttributeModifier.replace("src", Model.of(PATH_TO_IMAGE + "\\IMG" + Id + ".jpg")));
add(ci);
```

This changes the src-attribute of your img-tag according to your desired logic, prevents browser-caching where undesired but enables caching where possible.